# Why doesn't sending alpha characters work, but sending digits does?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using a slightly modified version of Deebu Jacob's ASP.NET web method call using AJAX (jQuery) example [here](http://deebujacob.blogspot.com/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html).  I've modified the CodeBehind to take a string instead of an int, but if I try to send an alpha string, I get no JS Alert when I click the button.  If on the other hand I send a string of digits, it works, even with blanks & decimal points.  I've added a second function to allow me to send variables instead of the hardcoded example on the page, which works just fine.

I think I'm missing a concept in the `contentType` or `dataType` of the AJAX call, which I just don't understand yet.  I've tried changing the dataType to `text` and the `contentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, but was unable to get either to work.

HTML/ASP (this example works, if you change one of the variables to contain alpha characters, it won't):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="JQueryAJAXwithIntExample.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function asyncServerCall(userid) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetData',
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testMe() {
        var suffix = ".159";
        var text = "314" + suffix;
        asyncServerCall(text);
    }
</script>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="testMe();" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CodeBehind (only change is input datatype from int to string in GetData method):

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace JQueryAJAXwithIntExample
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string GetData(string userid)
    {
        /*You can do database operations here if required*/
        return "My user ID is: " + userid;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

My ultimate goal is to pass back a string or series of strings to the server to be processed into mail & SQL objects for the Online RMA project I'm working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this:

```
 data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
```

Should be this:

```
data: "{'userid':'" + userid + "'}",
```

Note the single quotes around the string value.

Comment: Incredible!  You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out, and I wasn't even looking in the right place!  Thanks so much for the quick help.  While your solution works, why does it work (EG why do digits work, but not alphas)?  Do you know?

Comment: No problem, i know how it goes!  The compiler requires the quotes the same reason all languages use quotes to denote strings and numbers.  How does the compiler know when a string starts and ends without the quotes?  Also, how would it know the difference between the Number One and one as a string?